# After upgrade to asp.net MVC 4, dictionary parameters sent via ajax are improperly deserialized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using this jquery code to POST to an action:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Home/SaveConfigData",
    data: JSON.stringify({ id: idStr, add: add, remove: remove })
});
```

The json object is as follows:

```
{
    "id" : "24af6",
    "add" : [{
            "Key" : "99061b",
            "Value" : ["p1"]
        }, {
            "Key" : "99061c",
            "Value" : ["O1"]
        }
    ],
    "remove" : []
}
```

Here is the `SaveConfigData` function:

```
public void SaveConfigData(string id, Dictionary<string, List<string>> add, Dictionary<string, List<string>> remove)
{
}
```

Using asp.net MVC 3, this works as expected. The `add` dictionary is deserialized properly from the json object and the `remove` parameter is deserialized as null.  However, upon upgrading to asp.net MVC 4 the `add` parameter is still deserialized properly, but the `remove` dictionary is no longer null. Instead it looks like this:

```
{ key = "controller", value = ["Home"] },
{ key = "action", value = ["SaveConfigData"] }
```

Swapping the `add` and `remove` parameters within the JSON object results in the `remove` parameter being properly deserialized and the `add` argument now containing the "controller"/"home" data.